# How can I download big files in Deno?

Tags: javascript, deno

I'm trying to download a 10GB file, but only 4GB get saved to disk, and memory is growing a lot.

```
const res = await fetch('https://speed.hetzner.de/10GB.bin');
const file = await Deno.open('./10gb.bin', { create: true, write: true })

const ab = new Uint8Array(await res.arrayBuffer())
await Deno.writeAll(file, ab)
```

Comment: Does it throw an error at 4GB or the script ends correctly?

Comment: It ended without errors

Comment: That's weird, I'll try to replicate.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're buffering the response, that's why the memory is growing.

---

`Deno.open` now returns a `FsFile` which contains a `WritableStream` in `.writable` property, so you can just pipe the response to it.

```js
const res = await fetch('https://speed.hetzner.de/10GB.bin');
const file = await Deno.open('./10gb.bin', { create: true, write: true })

await res.body.pipeTo(file.writable);
file.close();
```

If you want to do something else instead of writing to a file, `res.body` is a [`ReadableStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream), so you could async iterate over it.

```
for await (const chunk of res.body) {
   // do something with each chunk
}
```

---

Regarding why it stops at 4GB I'm not sure, but it may have to do with `ArrayBuffer` / `UInt8Array` limits, since 4GB is around 2³² bytes, which is the limit of `TypedArray`, [at least in most runtimes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Invalid_array_length).

---

*Updated my answer for latest Deno version*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it'll take a while to download the file to confirm it's working :P

Comment: With this approach i just get all files with 2KB. Code here: https://jsfiddle.net/1t6385aw/

Answer (score 1):

here is another shorter version.

```
const res = await fetch('https://speed.hetzner.de/10GB.bin');
const file = await Deno.open('./10gb.bin', { create: true, write: true });

await res.body?.pipeTo(file.writable);
file.close();
```