# How to convert an arrayBuffer to a Uint8Array, in Deno?

Tags: javascript, deno

I'm using the fetch api to download an image in Deno. On the Response object, i'm calling the arrayBuffer() method, to get the final data of the response:

```
const response = await fetch('https://www.example.com/someimage.jpg')
const data = await response.arrayBuffer();//This returns an arrayBuffer.
```

Then i want to write this data into a file, just like you would do in Node:

```
await Deno.writeFile('./someimage.jpg' ,data)
```

The image turns out empty. The docs say Deno.writeFile expects a Uint8Array, but i have no clue how to construct this from the arrayBuffer, that is received from the fetch response.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to pass the [`ArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) to the `Uint8Array` constructor

> You cannot directly manipulate the contents of an ArrayBuffer;
> instead, you create one of the typed array objects or a DataView object which represents the buffer in a specific format, and use that to read and write the contents of the buffer.

```js
new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
```

---

```
const response = await fetch('https://www.example.com/someimage.jpg')
const data = await response.arrayBuffer();//This returns an arrayBuffer.
await Deno.writeFile('./someimage.jpg' , new Uint8Array(data))
```

Comment: Yes i actually just saw this on another post, and realized it has nothing to do with Deno, just normal JS :D

Comment: Exactly, that's just plain JS :).

Comment: In case you want to stream to the file, instead of buffering, check my answer over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61945050/how-can-i-download-big-files-in-deno/61945064#61945064

Answer (score 2):

Hmm... according to the docs (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) you simply do the following:

```js
// const data = await response.arrayBuffer();
const data = new ArrayBuffer(2); // Mock
const convertedData = new Uint8Array(data);

console.log(convertedData);
```